# Print symbol of file .o

Tags: symbols, nm

I want to print symbol of .o file (same of nm command).
I iterate on each section. And use this condition:

```
if (section[i].sh_type == SHT_SYMTAB)
      {
                        sym = (Elf64_Sym *)((char *)content + 
                        section[i].sh_offset);
      }
```

When I have my Elf64_Sym struct, i want print the symbol name. The struct is:

```
typedef struct {
    uint32_t      st_name;
    unsigned char st_info;
    unsigned char st_other;
    uint16_t      st_shndx;
    Elf64_Addr    st_value;
    uint64_t      st_size;
} Elf64_Sym;
```

How to print the st_name ? His type is uint32_t.
I don't understand how to print it.

An idea ?
Thanks you !

Comment: I don't remember if it's an offset or an index into a string table. It's one of those anyway.

Comment: Yes thanks. But how to acces to string table ?

Answer (score 0):

the `st_name` is an offset in the `.shstrtab`.

The string you're searching for is `(char *)(addr of shstrtab) + sym->st_name;`